# DIV Background Positioning With Padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, jsfiddle

I have a check mark that I want to put next to text in a button but when i do Background:left center; it works but i would like to add padding and stuff like that to it, is there any way I can do it with the code provided at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FzxKy/1/)? I would like to center the check mark and space it out a bit.

```
.Button {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:auto;
    color:#CCC
}

.Button:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.Check{
    background:url('http://67.184.73.19/Munet/Assets/Pictures/OffTick.png') no-repeat;
}

.Check:hover {
    background:url('http://67.184.73.19/Munet/Assets/Pictures/Tick.png') no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Button Check" style="background-color:rgb(69,72,77);">Test</div>
```

Comment: if i did this http://jsfiddle.net/FzxKy/2/ i want there to be equal padding on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to your fiddle updated with the tick in place:

```
.Button {
  padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:auto;
  color:#CCC
}

.Button:hover {
  color:#FFF;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.Check{
  background:url('http://67.184.73.19/Munet/Assets/Pictures/OffTick.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 15px;
  OR: background-position: 5px center;
}

.Check:hover {
  background:url('http://67.184.73.19/Munet/Assets/Pictures/Tick.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 15px;
  OR: background-position: 5px center;
}
```

Update:

Also make sure as per GordonsBeard's answer that you learn WHY this worked: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=10px%20200px

Comment: If the size of the font ever changes then you have hardcoded the padding to fit only within the size of the supplied button. By keeping one of the `center` tags in `background-position` then you can make sure that it will at least always be vertically aligned.

Comment: True, but in the same sense, if you have an image which is not square, or does not look correct centred, then you would have to hard-code it. However, I agree in this case that `5px center` is the better option. Moral of the story; learn what `background-position` does and use it correctly in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `background-poisition` tag.

```
background-position: <spacefromleft> <spacefromtop>;
```

Or you can declare it within the same background declaration.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-position

```
.Check{
    background:url('OffTick.png') no-repeat 10px center;
}

.Check:hover {
    background:url('Tick.png') no-repeat 10px center;
}
```

If you'd like to have the Text match up with the background, then just make sure to supply correct padding on your `.Button` (ie: have larger padding on the left side than you have on the remaining three other sides).

Comment: What do you mean by "equal padding"? You can declare anything instead of the `10px`. You can use `0.5em` or `5%`.